# Set Property used in subsequent create item task have blank values

Tags: workflow, orchardcms, orchardcore

Followed [Orchard Core Workflows Walkthrough: Content Approval](http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/orchard-core-workflows-walkthrough-content-approval) blog

and created a 3 step workflow:

1. Starting event HTTP Post with raw JSON content
2. Set "NewsItem" property task using JSON.parse(readBody()) value
3. Create content item task with Content Properties, where I'm trying to use the NewsItem property defined before, e.g. "Author": "{{ NewsItem.Author }}" etc. I have the complete JSON structure (which works with hardcoded values).

Ran the workflow and the result is  … that the newly created news item content has blank values all over. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/orchard-core-workflows-walkthrough-content-approval had it wrong. Need to use Workflow.Properties["MyProperty"].PropertyName instead of {{MyProperty.PropertyName}}

Comment: Thank you so much @Miha for answering your own question, appreciated.